# Reddit API Oauth2 "user required"

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, dotnet-httpclient, c++-cx

I am trying to get the installed app to work with Oauth2 on Reddit's api. I am using Windows runtime api's httpclient to make requests, and webauthenticationbroker to get the code to do the GET request to receive the token. I requested a token by using this:

```
https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=" + client_id + "&response_type=code&state=" + "testing" + "&redirect_uri=http://abcd.com&duration=" + "permanent" + "&scope=" + "vote,identity"
```

And got a code back, so I used POST on this (with the content type being: application/x-www-form-urlencoded):

```
https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
```

with the body being this:

```
grant_type=https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client&\
device_id="+id + "&code=" + code
```

(code and id is the code received in the first step and id is a generated UUID)

Then I got something like this back:

```
{"access_token": "--5e65dP1dI_1vgLbqvi7zRB6cnU", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 3600, "scope": "*"}
```

So I extracted the token and got this:

```
--5e65dP1dI_1vgLbqvi7zRB6cnU
```

Then I tried to do a GET request on https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me with these headers:

```
   {
  User-Agent: (testUWP client by /u/bored_reddit_user)
  Authorization: bearer --5e65dP1dI_1vgLbqvi7zRB6cnU
}
```

I got these headers back with status code 403 reason phrase forbidden:

```
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Server: cloudflare-nginx
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
  x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
  CF-RAY: 23f5127a6a2911a1-SJC
  Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 03:42:58 GMT
  x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
  access-control-allow-origin: *
  X-Moose: majestic
  x-reddit-tracking: https://pixel.redditmedia.com/pixel/of_destiny.png?v=BZoi0ikdGrSYn9U9xM6GWeYcRRb0W50fSQuGYb1Q8Oe7E5WVB6qTA4hRqlx9vDfpLOKzpE3Z5Wo%3D
  x-content-type-options: nosniff
  x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
  access-control-expose-headers: X-Reddit-Tracking, X-Moose
}{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}
```

and this content:

```
{"explanation": "Please log in to do that.", "reason": "USER_REQUIRED"}
```

I am at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me out?

Comment: What's the reason for using the `installed_client` grant type? It's only useful for making requests without a user context - which [https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_api_v1_me) seems like it needs a user context in order to return the currently authenticated user. Have you tried using `authorization_code` for the grant type?

Comment: Thanks @ZanyCadence that worked. Is there any page explaining each grant type? I would have thought that the `installed_client` type made sense for a client that would be installed on the user's computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This wiki page on the reddit github](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2) gives a pretty good overview of reddit's implementation of OAuth2 and the different `grant_types` and what circumstances they are appropriate for. [This page](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/oauth2-app-types) has some more information. I'm suspecting that reddit doesn't want you storing the client secret in an app that you install on a user's device since you can't keep it secure, and a user could figure out your CLIENT_ID.

I'm glad my comment could point you in the right direction, if you could accept this answer, I'd appreciate the rep.